# Creating a Closure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, closures

I've have functions in Matlab that takes two arguments, an image and a kernel and does various image processing applications on it. The signature is Gen_Filt(kernel,img) for various filtering operations. I'm trying to create a second function that closes over the  filterings operation with a specific kernel so it can do a particular operation with images.

```
function [closure] =Close_Over(General,kernel)
    function[out_img]=inner(img)
        
        out_img=General(kernel,img);
    
    end
closure=@inner;


end
```

So this will take a specific type of filtering operation (Gen_Filt signature) and a specific kernel and return a function handler with the kernel bound to that specific filtering operation. However, it seems to call the filtering operation function and gives the following error:

> Error in Gen_Filt (line 61)
>
> out_img=conv2(img,kernel,'same');

which makes me think it's trying to evaluate the filtering operation Gen_Filt before I can call the handler with a specific image argument.

Do I understand the problem correctly and/or am I making a mistake?

Comment: What is `Gen_Filt`? Your code snipped doesn’t even reference it! And what is the actual error message? Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. It’s hard to understand exactly what you did and where the error is generated with the information you’ve given.

Comment: Gen_Filt is a function I made that takes two parameters, (kernel,img) and it just does the convolution as shown with conv2. That’s the only line in the function because I was just testing it out. I wasn’t expecting it to be called.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't explain how you call this function, or what the exact error message is that you get (you only share the part of the error message that says where it happens, the part that describes the error itself is not there!).

Comment: For example, maybe you call `Close_Over(Gen_Filt,my_kernel)`, in which case you are trying to call `Gen_Filt`. In MATLAB, writing `Gen_Filt` is the same as writing `Gen_Filt()`. You would need to call `Close_Over(@Gen_Filt,my_kernel)`. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre], then we can see what the actual problem was.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It was just that, I didn't call it with ```@Gen_Filt```. I don't know if that is enough to make an answer or if I should delete this, but it was just a stupid mistake. Thank you for your help

Comment: By the way, you can create the same closure using a simpler syntax: `my_filter = @(img)Gen_Filt(kernel,img)`, with `kernel` known in the current workspace. Then, `my_filter(some_image)` will apply the `Gen_Filt` function with `kernel` as it existed when you created the closure (which is called anonymous function in MATLAB).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned there are problems with the code you have provided. But, for purposes of answering the title of the post, here is how you create a closure, using nested functions to capture variables in MATLAB.

```
function fun = createPlusOneFunc

    x = 0; % x is captured
    fun = @inner

    function out = inner(y)
        x = x+y;
        out = x;
    end

end

>> fun = createPlusOneFunc();
>> out = fun(1) % Increments captured variable state by 1.
>> out = fun(2) % Increments captured variable state by 2.
```

Comment: Thank you, it was in fact how I was calling it. I didn't add the @ in Gen_Filt and the function was getting called with no arguments instead of passing it as a parameter as a function handler. Slipped my mind because I'm used to python